Wix Patch generation erros
I used transformation to generate components for the files and each time the transformation generates new GIDs. This can be probably a problem

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wix="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
                xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
                exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

  <!--Load all components-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Filter components-->
  <xsl:key name="pdb-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />

  <!--Override SAMPLE.exe component-->
  <xsl:key name="sampleExe-search" match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe']" use="@Id" />  
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('sampleExe-search', @Id)]" >
    <Component Id="cmpSample" Guid="{@Guid}">
      <File Id="filSample" Source="$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe"/>
      <ProgId Id="SAMPLE Weather file" Description="Weather information used to route ships over the oceans" Icon="Sample.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes">
        <Extension Id="sps" Advertise="yes">
          <MIME ContentType="application/sps" Default="yes" />
          <Verb Id="open" Command="&amp;Open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" Sequence="1" />
        </Extension>
      </ProgId> 
    </Component>
    <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="60F4A4B3-DD4D-4FD6-B6AE-9C5EB8FCC0D1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Condition="CREATE_DESKTOP_ICON">
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\TechGroup\SAMPLE_9" Name="DesktopShortcutEnabled" Value="1"></RegistryValue>
      <Shortcut Name="SAMPLE_9" Directory="DesktopFolder" Target="[#filSample]" Icon="Sample.exe"></Shortcut>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="MenuShortcut" Guid="771174C2-CAC8-4E32-9BC6-C91D5458C9FA" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Condition="CREATE_MENU_ITEMS">
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\TechGroup\SAMPLE_9" Name="MenuShortcutEnabled" Value="1"></RegistryValue>
      <Shortcut Name="SAMPLE_9" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Target="[#filSample]" Icon="Sample.exe"></Shortcut>
    </Component>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('sampleExe-search', @Id)]" >
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpSample" />
    <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
    <ComponentRef Id="MenuShortcut" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--Override SAMPLE.exe.cofig component-->
  <xsl:key name="sampleExeConfig-search" match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe.config']" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('sampleExeConfig-search', @Id)]" >
    <Component Id="cmpSampleConfig" Guid="{@Guid}">
      <File Id="filSampleConfig" Source="$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe.config" />
    </Component>     
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('sampleExeConfig-search', @Id)]" >
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpSampleConfig" />  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

because when generating a patch I get a list of errors for each component. Since the list of components changes each time new GUIs are generated
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpyCS6YyDTyJkQgc8huzIZDCVWgKE' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpyFmO.0Y9VC3vYYMMmrdEzut86QE' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpy_JwZlrA0E.z.S5kNPQVrbh8eDE' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpyhmgT96wXgO6xXU6TQAq_c_i1XE' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpz.VA3sXmzkRwYFkiGBOVekughW8' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpz43YohzMGP9rXZZCPv8BQdEo2ZA' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzKkjlAgCv0Bt1Ua__5X2MYNhyFg' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzeCdz2zW17T3jTD6M_Tb6v4JIYU' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzfMfn0XaGQpis0F6xJ6D672J08A' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzkJaQ576cXT1n5UZiudak0QTE_4' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzrVlTC_vmvuBdNrhK07LvzTa2pc' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : error WIX0305: Removing component 'cmpzroMeoHBn0Bpu91Sux3KBINena0' from feature 'ProductFeature' is not supported. Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'RTM'. Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.
C:\patch creation\new\SAMPLE_9.msi : warning WIX1110: Component 'cmpDuCAJnvh7iERisroNVs4ez1Xrfg' was added to feature 'ProductFeature' in the transform 'RTM'. If you cannot guarantee that this feature will always be installed, you should consider adding new components to new top-level features to prevent prompts for source when installing this patch.

real screen of errors
My Patch.wsx file look like this:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Patch
    AllowRemoval="yes"
    DisplayName="Product Patch v$(Version)"
    Description="Product Patch v$(Version)"
    MoreInfoURL="https://wixtoolset.org/"
    Manufacturer="WiX Toolset"
    Classification="Update">

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="patch.cab">
      <PatchBaseline
        Id="RTM1"
        BaselineFile="SAMPLE_9_old.msi"
        UpdateFile="SAMPLE_9.msi" />
    </Media>

    <PatchFamily Id="SequenceFamily" Version="1.1.1" />
  </Patch>
</Wix> 

And i build it with this command:
wix build -define Version=2.0 -bindpath C:\Users\purbanski\source\repos\SAMPLE-onroad\src\SAMPLEonroad\SAMPLEonroadInstallerWix\bin\x86\Release\en-us -bindpath C:\Users\purbanski\source\repos\SAMPLE-onroad\src\SAMPLEonroad\SAMPLEonroadInstallerWix\bin\x86\Release\en-us  -out MyPatchV1V2.msp Patch.wxswix build -define Version=2.0 -bindpath C:\Users\purbanski\source\repos\SAMPLE-onroad\src\SAMPLEonroad\SAMPLEonroadInstallerWix\bin\x86\Release\en-us -bindpath C:\Users\purbanski\source\repos\SAMPLE-onroad\src\SAMPLEonroad\SAMPLEonroadInstallerWix\bin\x86\Release\en-us  -out MyPatchV1V2.msp Patch.wxs

I traing build patch

If you generate unique GUIDs during harvesting then MSPs will not be possible. That is a fundamental design limitation of the Windows Installer.

Thanks for respond Rob its helped. That's why I recently switched from using HeatDirectory Transforms, to using HarvestDirectory and it solved my last problem.

But I have another two problems
1)
when I building my patch I get this warning
S c:\onroadWixInstaller> wix build -define Version=2.0  -out PatchV1V2.msp Patch.wxs
wix.exe : warning WIX1099: Changing the ProductCode in a patch is not recommended because the patch cannot be uninstalled nor can it be sequenced along with other patches for the target product. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/applying-major-upgrades-by-patching-the-local-installation-of-the-product for more information.

My Product Package looks like that:
Package ProductCode="*" Compressed="yes" Language="$(var.Language)" 
           Manufacturer="$(var.Company)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Version="$(var.BuildVersion)">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.NewerVersionInstalled)"
        Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_40_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />

And Patch file looks like that
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Patch Id="*"
    AllowRemoval="no"
    DisplayName="SPOS 9 Patch v$(Version)"
    Description="SPOS 9 Patch v$(Version)"
    MoreInfoURL="https://wixtoolset.org/"
    Manufacturer = "MeteoGroup"
    Classification="Update">

    <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="patch.cab">
      <PatchBaseline
        Id="RTM"
        BaselineFile="C:\patch creation\old\MY_APP.msi"
        UpdateFile="C:\patch creation\new\MY_APP.msi" >
        <Validate ProductId="no" />
      </PatchBaseline>      
    </Media>

    <PatchFamily Id="SequenceFamily" Version="$(Version)" />
  </Patch>
</Wix>

What can I ask for a hint as to why i get this warning ?
2)
My secend problem is :
When I run the installation of my patch, I get the Maintenance Form witch i can chose repear or remove last instance of my instalation.
can chose repear or remove last instance of my instalation.
When i chuse repear then patch innstaled. I d't want UI when i insttaling patch. What I should do ?
